# It doesn't move to the next image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a slideshow. I have created two buttons because I want to do it in two ways. One way is when I press the next button to move to the next image(single image movement) and when I press the slideshow button to make it move along with not pressing a button. I didn't manage to fix it. Please help me if you can.

```js
var img = new Array();

img[0] = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5101NtSnx0L._AC_.jpg";
img[1] = "https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/1200x0/filters%3Aformat%28jpg%29/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fimageserve%2F5ecc17cdfd6d6700060f826c%2F0x0.jpg";

img[2] = "https://cdn.episode.ninja/file/episodeninja/4090819.jpg";
img[3] = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f0/e5/a9/f0e5a984f263b7ecb5c9cd26a493a115.jpg";

function Next() {
  if (i < img.length - 1)
    i++;
  else
    i = 0;
  document.getElementById("img1").src = img[i];
}
startslideshow() {
  id = window.setInterval("Next()", 1000);
  var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  id2 = window.clearTimeout("Cancel()", x * 1000)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="img1" height="300" width="300" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ho7KT0UEARE/VPbiU-U_KSI/AAAAAAAALVM/iZdcRS6KHvQ/s1600/Acrobatty%2BBunny%2B-%2BRobert%2BMcKimson%2B(3).jpg" /> <br>
  <button id="Next" onclick="Next()"> Next </button>
  <button onclick="startslideshow()">startSlideShow</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You didn't iniitalize `i`.

Comment: `startslideshow()` should call `Next()` periodically using `setInterval()`.

Comment: var i = 0; ? yes I have initialize it I just didn't copy it .It doesn't work too

Comment: that is the code of slideshow if it is usefull
  function startslideshow(){
  
  
id = window.setInterval("Next()", 1000);
 var x = document.getElementById("txt").value;
 id2= window.clearTimeout("Cancel()",x*1000)
}

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/x92gakb3/

Comment: @amanjonheyp Add the slideshow code to the snippet in the question.

Comment: @D.Seah it doesnt work.. :/

Comment: @Barmar I have added it

Comment: try this one https://jsfiddle.net/x92gakb3/2/

Comment: @D.Seah yeah it works :D Thank you!!

Comment: you are welcome. cool cartoons :-) Posting the answer for completeness.

Comment: I don't understand your use of `clearTimeout()`. The argument should be an ID returned by `setTimeout()`, not a string. And what is the second argument for?

Comment: @Barmar the second argument you mean the next step?Is to fill this table and after this table to  create another similar table but in 1 line only with 9 cells

Comment: I mean `x * 1000`. That looks like a time period, but `clearTimeout()` doesn't take a time period argument. Maybe you meant to call `setTimeout()`?

Comment: yes that exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution that we have came up with

```
<body>
  <img id="img1" height="300" width="300" src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ho7KT0UEARE/VPbiU-U_KSI/AAAAAAAALVM/iZdcRS6KHvQ/s1600/Acrobatty%2BBunny%2B-%2BRobert%2BMcKimson%2B(3).jpg" /> <br>
  <button id="Next" onclick="Next()"> Next </button>
  <button onclick="startslideshow()">startSlideShow</button>
  <button onclick="stopslideshow()">stopSlideShow</button>
</body>
```

```js
var img = new Array();
var cur = 0;
var timer = null;

img[0] = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/5101NtSnx0L._AC_.jpg";
img[1] = "https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/1200x0/filters%3Aformat%28jpg%29/https%3A%2F%2Fspecials-images.forbesimg.com%2Fimageserve%2F5ecc17cdfd6d6700060f826c%2F0x0.jpg";

img[2] = "https://cdn.episode.ninja/file/episodeninja/4090819.jpg";
img[3] = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/f0/e5/a9/f0e5a984f263b7ecb5c9cd26a493a115.jpg";

function Next() {
  cur = (cur < img.length - 1) ? cur + 1 : 0;
  document.getElementById("img1").src = img[cur];
}

function startslideshow() {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    Next();
  }, 500);
}

function stopslideshow() {
  if (timer) {
     clearInterval(timer);
     timer = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: The previous will be like this? right? function Prev() {
  cur = (cur >img.length - 1) ? cur + 1 : 0;
  document.getElementById("img1").src = img[cur];
}

Comment: Thank you once again :D